# Excel - Increment vlookup column index when dragging down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a vlookup which needs to check the next column to the right each time it is dragged down a cell. So if the vlookup is first entered in cell A3 then it would be:

```
=vlookup($A$1, $A$1:$E$1, 2, False)
```

Then if I drag it down to A4 it would become:

```
=vlookup($A$1, $A$1:$E$1, 3, False)
```

So Far the only way I have come across to increment the number is to use COLUMNS as the index number, but this only works when dragging horizontally. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ROW function which returns the row number of its own cell.

```
A3: =vlookup($A$1, $A$1:$E$1, row()-1, False)
```

Comment: +1 cause its your best answer so far